# how to disable screen overlay permission for all android app from my app?

Tags: android, permissions, overlay, android-5.0-lollipop

I want no overlay app notification from other apps on my app. But there is a problem with android version 5.0 and 5.1 for blocking apps with overlay permission. Please help me

Comment: what do you mean? You want your app to obtain draw overlay permission and deny it from other apps at the same time?

Comment: I want to disable overlay permission of all overlay permission obtained app from my app. I don't need overlay permission for my app.